# Use of loops and seasonal adjustment in R with multivariate timeseries

Tags: r, loops, time-series

My goal is to adjust data seasonally and save only seasonal factors. 
My data consists of 60+ time series. As you see, one of my problems is that there
is a lot of time series that I need to adjust at once. Here’s my try to do this in R:

```
library("timeDate")
library("timeSeries")
library("seasonal")

mDxts <- structure(c(35.8, 41.6, 35.9, 36.9, 42.43, 36.067,28.67, 29.53, 32.83, 29.867,23.9, 20.8, 21.167, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 149.67,108.89, 89.067, 83.33, 77.2,64.91, 50.2, 48, 62.13, 52.93,43.2, 38.8, 37.9, 19, 18, 17, 16.5, 16, 15.5, 15), class = c("xts","zoo"), .indexCLASS = "yearqtr", tclass = "yearqtr", .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", index = structure(c(946684800,954547200, 962409600, 970358400, 978307200, 986083200, 993945600,1001894400, 1009843200, 1017619200, 1025481600, 1033430400, 1041379200,1491004800, 1498867200, 1506816000, 1514764800, 1522540800, 1530403200,1538352000), tzone = "", tclass = "yearqtr"), .Dim = c(20L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("depall", "ref"))) 
ll<-lapply(mDxts, function(e) ts(e,start=c(2000,1),frequency=4))
#I. Seasonal adjustment and saving only d10 component:
sf<-sapply(ll,function(e) try(seas(e,x11="",na.action=na.exclude, transform.function = "none",x11.mode="logadd",arima.model="(0 1 1) (0 1 0)",regression.aictest = NULL, outlier=NULL,x11.save="d10")))
```

As I understand, my main problem is that performing `sf<-sapply(st,function(e) try(seas(e, x11.save="d10"))` I obtain a list  where each element is a list with all d10, d11 and so on (take a look by `SF.df<-as.data.frame(SF)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, time passed, and now I'm able to give an answer to the questions.
I needed to adjust seasonally a lot a data simultaneously and then to recalculate them at one time.

1. Firstly, one problem was that the result of seasonal adjustment was saved as list. The answer is in using fuction `final` from `seasonal`:

   ```
   sa<-sapply(st,function(e) try(final(seas(e,x11="",na.action=na.exclude,
   transform.function = "none",x11.mode="logadd",arima.model="(0 1 1) (0 1 0)",
   regression.aictest = NULL, outlier=NULL))))
   ```
2. To save the seasonal factor a function `series` from the same package was needed:

   ```
   sf<-sapply(st,function(e) try(series(seas(e,x11="",na.action=na.exclude,
    transform.function = "none",x11.mode="logadd",arima.model="(0 1 1) (0 1 0)",
   regression.aictest = NULL, outlier=NULL),"d10")))
   ```